# Export the animation labeled with time in the animation?

Tags: export, animation

I want to export the solution of a equation

```
eqn = D[u[t, x, y], t, t] == D[u[t, x, y], x, x] + 
D[u[t, x, y], y, y]/2 + (1 - u[t, x, y]^2) (1 + 2 u[t, x, y]);
fun = First[u /. NDSolve[{eqn, u[0, x, y] == Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], 
u[t, -5, y] == u[t, 5, y], u[t, x, -5] == u[t, x, 5], 
Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, x, y] == 0}, 
u, {t, 0, 4}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]]
```

Export:

```
pl = Table[Plot3D[fun[t, x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All],
{t, 0, 4, 1}];
Export["example for animation.gif", pl, "DisplayDurations" -> 1, 
"AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity]
```

I just want to export a .GIF file to show the motion of the solution with the time step displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pl = Table[
  Plot3D[fun[t, x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["Time = " <> ToString[t], Bold]], {t, 0, 4, 1}];
Export["time.gif", pl, "DisplayDurations" -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers! I open the .GIF using IE browser, but it does not motion. Do I must use the QuickTime Player to open it? For your answer, I guess you used browser to open it...

Comment: @lxy I used Chrome as a browser to open.